# FULLTEXT search on two fields faster than on one field

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have two fields in a table in my database with a FULLTEXT index: one with about 60 characters content on average, the other with about 400. I'm doing a FULLTEXT search on this table like this:

```
... MATCH (table.field1, table.field2) AGAINST ("some string") ...
```

This takes about 8 seconds.

```
... MATCH (table.field1) AGAINST ("some string") ...
```

This takes about 18 seconds.

```
... MATCH (table.field2) AGAINST ("some string") ...
```

This takes about 22 seconds.

---

What strikes me is that when I do a search on more fields, the query is faster! I checked several times again, but the times stay like this. How is this possible? Would it be a good idea to add dummy data to add another field to the search and make it even faster?

Comment: How did you set up your indexes?

Comment: On what columns did you set an index? You can see it in phpMyAdmin (assuming your using it) under 'Structure'

Comment: I meant the indexes, not the column types ;-). Click on 'Structure', scroll down to 'Indexes'. What do you see there?

Comment: Thanks, two seperated FULLTEXT indexes? Or one FULLTEXT indexes with two columns? I think the last one, that makes the single field slow, because it can't use that index then i think.

And do an EXPLAIN on the fast and the slow query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have one FULLTEXT index for both fields. That what makes the single field query slow, because it can't use that index.